# Run tasks issue after androidX migration

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I have run tasks issues when I run my project:

```
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild   
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugManifest
      Execute taskAction
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript    
:app:compileDebugAidl   
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
```

In build output I got this message:

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s
26 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 23 up-to-date
```

I migrate to Android X, is it possible that I didn't do it correctly and so I have this kind of trouble? Are these errors dangers? How could I fix this? Tell me if you need to see `AndroidManifest` or `build.gradle` or some other codes.
Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

This is build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.application.packagename"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Build output:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest

> Task :app:processDebugResources
Changing the value for a property with a final value has been deprecated. This will fail with an error in Gradle 6.0.

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeProjectDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:signingConfigWriterDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:packageDebug
> Task :app:assembleDebug

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 23s
26 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 23 up-to-date
```

Comment: Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.

Comment: Can you update your questing with 'build.gradle', please? Maybe 'targetSdkVersion', 'compileSdkVersion' or some of your implementations are causing this warning

Comment: @just  forgive me for this question but I'm pretty new, where should i type '--warning-mode all'?

Comment: in the command line add those parameters to build command, for example: `./gradlew assembleDebug --warning-mode all`